# jquery swap multiple img src from one div to another

Tags: jquery, image

I trying to change a blog layout and need to change one img position from div id="img-origen" to div id="img-target". I almost have it but I am doing something wrong when printing the array...

This is the html code

```
<div id="blogPost">
    <div id="img-target" > 
        <img alt="" src="">
    </div>
    <!-- content here -->
    <div id="img-origen" > 
        <img alt="" src="image/test.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

I create the array with:

```
var newSrc = $("#img-origen img").map(function() {
  return $(this).attr("src");
  }).get();
  console.log(newSrc);
```

Print the array with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.each(newSrc, function(i, val) {
    $("#img-target img").attr("src", val);
  });
});
```

But I am printing the same img in all target-img, so all list item have the same image...

Can anyone guide me in the right direction_

Thanks

Comment: Do you have multiple elements with the same ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.each(newSrc, function(i, val) {
    $("#img-target img").eq(i).attr("src", newSrc[i]);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Working FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/djjaLfn9/)**
Use the swapping mechanism as follows: Take src of both images and then swap it.

```
var img1=$("#img-target img").attr("src");
var img2=$("#img-origen img").attr("src");

$("#img-origen img").attr("src",img1);
$("#img-target img").attr("src",img2);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var temp = $("#img-target img").attr("src");
    $("#img-target img").attr("src", $("#img-origen img").attr("src"));
    $("#img-origen img").attr("src", temp)
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, since first answer worked perfect didnt try you solution